# Is there a way to raise a compile time error when calling a given function several times in C++?

Tags: c++, compile-time, error-checking

Is there a way in C++ to design a function / add some "attributes" to it in such a way that calling it several times in the code would raise a compile time error?

To give a bit of background / motivation: I was programming on Mbed-OS and I did a couple of mistakes that look like:

```cpp
rtos::Thread thread;

[lots of code]

thread.start(persistent_function_1);

[lots of code in a setup function]

thread.start(persistent_function_2);
```

This had the (logical) consequence that the `persistent_function_1`, which should have been allowed to execute for the lifetime of the program, only got to execute until the thread was re-purposed to run `persistent_function_2`. It took me a long time to find this bug, and I was wondering if I can do something to my `thread.start` function to make sure I get a compiler error if I make this sort of mistake again.

Comment: There's got to be a  way to wrap `thread.start` in a template that sets a boolean or a counter and tests the boolean in a static assert. Of course then some yahoo's going to call `thread.start` without the template and you're no better off.

Comment: Yes, this would already be a nice improvement. I agree this could still fall through, but there could be a policy on the codebase that "one should not use naked thread declarations".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to coerce the C++ language directly to detect double invocation of `start()` at compile time (put differently, I don't think @user4581301's suggestion would work): to statically assert a property you'd need to somehow change the entity. I'm sure you could write a custom checker using [`clang`](http://clang.llvm.org/) but I guess that isn't what you are after. It would, obviously, be possible to have a run-time assertion which reports that an already `start()`ed thread is started again. Again, that doesn't seem to be what you are after.

The "obvious" solution is no to have "`[lots of code]`" in a function to start with. In fact, `std::thread` entirely side-steps that issue by enforcing that there is *no* code between the object declaration and its start: the `std::thread` is started upon construction. The setup with "`[lots of code]`" between the object declaration and the start would be something like

```
my::thread thread([&]{
        [lots of code]
        return persistent_function_1;
    }());
```

The caveat is that you'd need to set up your various variables sort of out of order. That is, the preferred approach would be to declare the `thread` object at the site where it is actually started:

```
[lots of code]
my::thread thread(persistent_function_1);
```

In both of these cases `my::thread` would be a trivial wrapper around `rtos::thread` which doesn't expose a separate `start()` method. As I don't know why `rtos::thread` separates construction and `start()` and a plausible reason could be the ability to set up various thread parameters, it may be reasonable to actually use two separate arguments to `my::thread`'s constructor:

1. A function taking a `my::thread::properties` entity as parameter which allows the necessary manipulations of the `thread` object.
2. The function to be started.

That is, something like

```
my::thread thread([](my::thread::properties& properties) {
    [lots of code manipulating the properties]
    },
    persistent_function_1);
```

This way, it remains possible to manipulate the `thread` but you can't possible `start()` a thread twice.

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't 100% sure it could be done, but every time I think something can't be done, it seems some wise guy drops a template metaprogram that does it. Often the template's so insane it's worse than the what it's trying to cure, but the real point I was trying to make is whatever you do to prevent re-calling `start`, someone's going to step around by directly calling `start`. The only sane thing to do is make prevention unnecessary or make the mistake obvious during code review.

Comment: @user4581301: I agree that quite often someone comes along and finds a way to do something thought to be impossible before (did that myself a long time ago when I found a function template deducing the size of a built-in array, i.e., what is `std::end()` for build-in array now). However, I don't think there is a way to change the static properties of a name and I don't see how different names could be used even if macros were involved. Thus, my proposal to address the problem is to use a different interface. To do that properly I'd need to understand more about `rtos::thread`, though.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to wrap the thread in a new manager object, with the rough shape of

```cpp
class thread_manager {
  rtos::Thread thread;
  const std::function<...> execution_function;
  /* .
     .
     . */

public:
  thread_manager(rtos::Thread _thread, std::function<...> function, ...)
    : thread { _thread }
    , execution_function { function }
    , ...

  void start();
}
```

and disallowing any other usage of threading (which can be justified on the basis of encapsulation, although as pointed out in comments, yahoos are always a risk).

Comment: C++ (like most programming languages) aims to help the programmer avoid unintended errors.   There is no preventing a "yahoo"  (aka those folks who willfully work around a constraint that someone has gone to the trouble of enforcing) from messing things up.   If code can be written to prevent something, someone else can either rewrite that code or find some evil workaround.    That's why there are non-technical enforcements (documentation, policy, firing people who willfully break the rules) that a compiler cannot enforce.

Answer (score 1):

There is no current mechanism for detecting an expression that appears twice. But you can torture the compiler to get something close

```cpp
namespace
{
    template<int>
    struct once
    {
        once() {}
        friend void redefine() {}
    };
}

#define ONCE(expr) (once<__COUNTER__>{}, (expr))
```

If `ONCE` ever appear twice in the same TU, the compiler will complain about redefining `redefine`.

```cpp
ONCE(thread.start(persistent_function_1));  // ok
ONCE(thread.start(persistent_function_2));  // error
```